# Erro settext verificando conexao de internet

Tags: android

Estou usando esse código para checar minha conexão com a internet, porém ele não permite que eu use o `setText()` para alterar um texto no layout, dá erro e fecha o app, alguém pode ajudar?

```
private void checkNetworkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeInfo != null && activeInfo.isConnected()) {

        boolean wifiConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
         boolean mobileConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;

        if(wifiConnected) {
            Log.i(TAG, "WIFI connected");
            stsRede.setText("Conectado no WiFi");
        } else if (mobileConnected){
            Log.i(TAG, "Mobile Connected");
            //stsRede.setText("Conectado no 3G");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG,"Neither Mobile nor WIFi connected.");
        //stsRede.setText("Sem conexão a internet");
    }
   }
```

Erro que retorna:

```
08-27 23:25:26.454: I/Adreno-EGL(31529): <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:410>: EGL                1.4 QUALCOMM build:     AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018_msm8226_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1__release_AU ()
08-27 23:25:26.454: I/Adreno-EGL(31529): OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: E031.24.00.08
08-27 23:25:26.454: I/Adreno-EGL(31529): Build Date: 03/07/14 Fri
08-27 23:25:26.454: I/Adreno-EGL(31529): Local Branch: 
08-27 23:25:26.454: I/Adreno-EGL(31529): Remote Branch: quic/LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.1
08-27 23:25:26.454: I/Adreno-EGL(31529): Local Patches: NONE
08-27 23:25:26.454: I/Adreno-EGL(31529): Reconstruct Branch: AU_LINUX_ANDROID_LNX.LA.3.5.1_RB1.04.04.02.048.018 + f2fd134 +  NOTHING
08-27 23:25:26.549: D/OpenGLRenderer(31529): Enabling debug mode 0
08-27 23:25:28.683: I/(31529): WIFI connected
08-27 23:25:28.685: D/AndroidRuntime(31529): Shutting down VM
08-27 23:25:28.685: W/dalvikvm(31529): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41920d40)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529): Process: br.com.renasti, PID: 31529
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable     to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.renasti/br.com.renasti.NovoRegActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2198)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2257)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:139)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1210)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at br.com.renasti.NovoRegActivity.checkNetworkConnection(NovoRegActivity.java:232)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at br.com.renasti.NovoRegActivity.onCreate(NovoRegActivity.java:57)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5248)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1110)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2162)
08-27 23:25:28.688: E/AndroidRuntime(31529):    ... 11 more
```

Pessoal, abaixo minha Class NovoRegActivity. Nela eu recupero o textview stsRede, porém não entendo o erro.

```
public class NovoRegActivity extends Activity {
Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();  
public Dados dados = new Dados();
private Uri fileUri;
private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;
private static final String MEDIA_TYPE_IMAGE = null;
private static final String TAG = null;
private TextView txtfoto;
private EditText edtBairro;
private TextView txtLatitude;
private TextView txtLongitude;
private TextView txtdata;
private Button btGps;
public int ano, mes, dia;
public TextView stsRede;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    //Remove barra de titulos
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_novo_reg);

    //Checa status de conexão com a internet
    checkNetworkConnection();
    //Recupera os id's vindo da activity NovoReg
    setupElements();
    //Checa status do gps
    checaStatusGps();
    //Inicia gps sem necessidade de clicar no botao. Apenas chamando o método
    startGPS();
    //Recupera data
    recuperaData();
}

//Verifica se gps está ativado, caso não esteja, solicita ativação
public void checaStatusGps(){

    LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    if (locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

    } else {

        //Depois configurar um Alert Box aqui antes avisando sobre o gps
        Toast.makeText(NovoRegActivity.this, "Por favor ative seu gps!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        //Chama tela de ativação do Gps
        Intent ligaGps = new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);   
        startActivity(ligaGps);   
    }

}

// Método usado para importar os elementos da classe R
public void setupElements(){

    //Recupera id txt foto e edt bairro
    txtfoto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtStatusFoto);
    edtBairro =  (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editBairro);
    txtLatitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLatitude);
    txtLongitude = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtLongitude);
    txtdata = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtdata);
    stsRede = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.stsRede);


    btGps = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnGps);
    btGps.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v){
            startGPS();
        }});
}

public void recuperaData() {
    //Recuperando data atual
    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    ano = calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR);
    mes = calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH);
    dia = calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

    //Seta na variavel dataRegistro
    txtdata.setText(dia + "/" + (mes+1)+ "/" +ano);
}

//Método que faz a leitura de fato dos valores recebidos do GPS
public void startGPS(){
    LocationManager lManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    LocationListener lListener = new LocationListener() {
        public void onLocationChanged(Location locat) {
            updateView(locat);
        }
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}
    };
    lManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, lListener);
}

//  Método que faz a atualização da tela para o usuário.
public void updateView(Location locat){
    Double latitude = locat.getLatitude();
    Double longitude = locat.getLongitude();

    txtLatitude.setText(latitude.toString());
    txtLongitude.setText(longitude.toString());

    //Log.i("Gps", "pegou!");
}


//Método para registrar a foto
public void foto(View v){

    File diretorio = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);

    String nomeImagem = diretorio.getPath()+ "/" + System.currentTimeMillis()+".jpg";

    // create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
    Intent novafoto = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);

    fileUri = Uri.fromFile(new File(nomeImagem)); 
    novafoto.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);

    // start the image capture Intent
    startActivityForResult(novafoto, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
}


//Método de retorno do arquivo gravado
private Uri getOutputMediaFileUri(String mediaTypeImage) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

//Método para recuperar status da câmera
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            //Alterar status de registro da foto visualmente
            txtfoto.setText("Foto Registrada!");

            // Image captured and saved to fileUri specified in the Intent
            Toast.makeText(this, "Foto Registrada", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            //Toast.makeText(this, "Registro de foto cancelado!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Falha na captura da imagem!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }

}

//Faz o registro no banco de dados e envia para WS
public void registrar(View v){

    //Checa campos vazios
    /*if (edtBairro.getText().toString().equals("") || txtfoto.getText().toString().equals("")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Existe campos vazios!" , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }*/

    //Verifica status internet
    if (stsRede.getText().toString().equals("Sem conexão a internet")){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Você precisa da internet para enviar o alerta!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        return;
    }

    //Gravando no banco de dados
    dados.setLatitude(txtLatitude.getText().toString());
    dados.setLongitude(txtLongitude.getText().toString());
    dados.setDataEnvio(txtdata.getText().toString());
    dados.setBairro(edtBairro.getText().toString());
    //Colocar evento aqui para registrar imagem no banco 
    BD bd = new BD (this);
    bd.inserir(dados);

    Log.i("BD","Salvou");

    Toast.makeText(this, "Enviado com sucesso!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

}


private void checkNetworkConnection() {
    ConnectivityManager connMgr =
        (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo activeInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

    if (activeInfo != null && activeInfo.isConnected()) {

        boolean wifiConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI;
         boolean mobileConnected = activeInfo.getType() == ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE;

        if(wifiConnected) {
            Log.i(TAG, "WIFI connected");
            //stsRede.setText("Conectado no WiFi");
        } else if (mobileConnected){
            Log.i(TAG, "Mobile Connected");
            //stsRede.setText("Conectado no 3G");
        }
    } else {
        Log.i(TAG,"Neither Mobile nor WIFi connected.");
        //stsRede.setText("Sem conexão a internet");
    }
   }
```

}

Comment: Para ajudar na analise recomendo colocar o erro que apresenta

Comment: Você está usando esse código em outra thread que não seja a principal?Caso positivo tente por um Handler antes de alterar o texto.

Comment: Verifique se `stsRede` é nulo. Talvez esteja a chamar o método `checkNetworkConnection()` antes de fazer `stsRede = findViewById()`

Comment: Se dissesse qual é a linha 232 ajudava :)

Comment: @ramaral era isso mesmo, eu chamei o método antes, agora deu certo.

Answer (score 0):

Está dando erro pois você não inicializou o objeto **stsRede**, portanto faça desta forma:

```
    EditText stsRede = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.stsRede); // Caso seja um EditText seu objeto stsRede
```

Caso seja um TextView, use:

```
    TextView stsRede = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.stsRede); // Caso seja um TextView seu objeto stsRede
```